# How to ignore white space when reading from a text file?

Tags: c

I want to fix my C program to ignore the extra white space just before the name.

For example, when the input read from `stdin` is:

```
11, Alan Turing,3.20
```

there is a space between the first comma and the name. I want to ignore this space and append the following line to **student.txt**:

```
11,Alan Turing,3.20
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student {
    int id;
    char name[300];
    float grade;
} Student;

int main() {
    Student s;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("student.txt", "a+");
    scanf("%d", &s.id);
    scanf("%[^1234567890]s", &s.name);
    s.name[strlen(s.name) - 1] = '\0';
    scanf("%f", &s.grade);
    fprintf(fp, "%d,%s,%.2f\n", s.id, s.name, s.grade);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't get whete is the input is it from a file or from stdin ?

Comment: I input the data to text file named student.txt, how to remove the extra space that appears as obvious in the post.

Comment: Please define your requirements more clearly. There are other spaces in the file. So which ones exactly do you need removed? Can there be unwanted spaces anywhere else? Is it exactly one space or can it be more/less/no spaces? Etc. The answers to these will change the solution that will work best.

Comment: Give detail about input expected, and output expected.

Comment: Please read my post very well sir, i want to remove the space between the first comma and name.

`11, Alan Turing,3.20`


i want to delete space between Alan and "," to be like that

`11,Alan Turing,3.20`

Comment: try `"%d, %299[^,],%f"`

Comment: BLUEPIXY the space created when entering data to the file not reading from the file

Comment: _i want to delete extra white space from part of the text file._ try `scanf(" %[^1234567890]",s.name);`

Comment: You didn't answer my questions. What you have described is only one case. The questions are trying to understand all the cases that the program needs to handle. If you insist on such a narrow problem space: `fprintf(fp,"%d,%s,%.2f\n",s.id,&s.name[1],s.grade);`

Comment: OK i understand your question sir, there is extra white space after the records, it's found on empty line. can you help me delete it?

Comment: try `"%d, %299[^,],%f"`

Answer (score 0):

Your scanset in the second `scanf` reads all non-digit characters.  This is not what you want to do.  You want to read all characters up to the next comma.

Try replacing your three `scanf` calls with:

```
scanf("%d, ", &s.id);
scanf("%[^,]", &s.name);
scanf(",%f", &s.grade);
```

and eliminate the assignment that you have in between.

Notice that it is the space character in the first `scanf` that removes the unwanted space.

Comment: don't understand your answer sir, i tried this but the program not exit after i entered the data.

Comment: `"%[^,]s"` --> this is incorrect.  `",%f\n"` trailing white-space is not advisable for `stdin`.

Comment: @chux You are right about the first, the `s` should be removed.  It was there in the original code and I forgot to remove it.  Funny, it worked even while I had it (clang, not gcc).  I sort of disagree with your second statement, but I see your point and I have also removed the trailing `\n` from the answer.  The first trailing space (in `"%d, "`) certainly cannot be removed, advisable or not.  The one in `",%f\n"` (as I had it originally) can be removed. It makes no harm if lines end properly and the user is patient enough to wait for the EOF.  However, this is probably what confused Maher...

Comment: Better to use `scanf("%d,", &s.id); scanf(" %[^,]", &s.name);` - move space to 2nd format.  By moving the space to the 2nd `scanf()`, the first scanf returns once white-space is encountered.  Leaving the space in the first is the same problem as the 3rd: `scanf()` does not return until non-white-space (or EOF occurs) follows the number.

Comment: @chux You're right about your suggestion, it is equivalent, only I still can't see why this is preferable.  There will certainly be white space after the comma (this is the problem we need to solve) and after the float (there is a new line there).  In any case, I think we've turned this into rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a quick parser, this reads an int skip non alpha char, store all char till find a digit then parse a float

I have done no modification after `stdin` parsing.
stdin:

```
45 foo bar 45.69
 45, toto, 78.5
```

stdout:

```
ID:45
NAME:foo bar
GRADE:45.69
ID:45
NAME:toto
GRADE:78.50
```

file content:

```
45,foo bar,45.69
45,toto,78.50
```

Prog:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                             
#include <stdlib.h>                                                            
#include <string.h>                                                            

typedef struct student {                                                       
    int id;                                                                    
    char name[256]; /* use aligned structures*/                                
    float grade;                                                               
} Student;                                                                     

int main() {                                                                   
    Student s;                                                                 
    FILE *fp;                                                                  
    char buf[BUFSIZ];                                                          
    char *p;                                                                   
    int i = 0;                                                                 

    fp = fopen("student.txt", "a+");                                           
    printf("Give id name and grade\n");                                        
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);                                            


    p = buf;                                                                   
    /* get id */                                                               
    s.id = strtol(p, &p, 10);                                                  
    if (!s.id) {                                                               
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad id");                                             
        return -1;                                                             
    }                                                                          
    /* skip non alpha char between int and name*/                              
    while (!isalpha(*p)) {                                                     
        p++;                                                                   
    }                                                                          

    /*copy name */                                                             
    while (!isdigit(*p)) {                                                     
        s.name[i++] = *p++;                                                    
    }                                                                          
    if (i == 0) {                                                              
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad name");                                           
        return -1;                                                             
    }                                                                          
    s.name[i] = '\0';                                                          
    i--;                                                                       
    /*remove trailing char at the end of the name */                           
    while(!isalpha(s.name[i])) {                                               
        s.name[i--] = '\0';                                                    
    }                                                                          
    /* parse grade */                                                          
    s.grade = strtof(p, &p);                                                   


    fprintf(fp,"%d,%s,%.2f\n",s.id,s.name,s.grade);                            
    fclose(fp);                                                                
    fp = fopen("student.txt","r");                                             
    if(fp != NULL) {                                                           
        while((fscanf(fp,"%d,%299[^,],%f", &s.id,s.name,&s.grade)) == 3) {     
            printf("ID:%d\n",s.id);                                            
            printf("NAME:%s\n",s.name);                                        
            printf("GRADE:%.2f\n",s.grade);                                    
        }                                                                      
        fclose(fp);                                                            
    } else  {                                                                  
        perror("student.txt");                                                 
    }                                                                          
    return 0;                                                                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a character within a string, you'll have to displace the following characters after the comma.

One may end up with a function like the one below, while they are many other methods that address this problem, I find this one to be simple and efficient.

```
void
trim_comma_spaces(char *string)
{
        char   *tmp;
        char   *ptr    = string;
        int    i;
        size_t len;

        ptr = string;
        while(1) {
                tmp = strchr(ptr, ',');

                if(!tmp)
                        break;

                for(i=0, tmp++; isspace(*(tmp+i)); i++);

                if(!i) {
                        ptr = tmp + 1;
                        continue;
                }

                len = strlen(tmp);

                /* memory areas may overlap? Use memmove */
                memmove(tmp, tmp+i, len - i);

                *(tmp + len - i) = '\0';

                ptr = tmp;
        }
}
```

For example

```
int
main(void)
{
        char *ptr;
        char *tmp;
        char string[] = "11,     \n\n\r\v\f      Alan Turing, 3.20\n12, \n\v\fJohn Doe, 3.19";

        printf("Before:\n%s\n", string);
        trim_comma_spaces(string);

        printf("after:\n%s\n", string);
        return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
Before:
11,



      Alan Turing, 3.20
12,


John Doe, 3.19
after:
11,Alan Turing,3.20
12,John Doe,3.19
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend starting with reading a *line* with `fgets()`.

Now scan the buffer with `"%d , %299[A-Za-z ] ,%f"`.  Be sure to test the `ssscanf()` result.

`"%d"`  Read any white space, read `int`.
`" , "`  Read any white space, comma, any white space
`"%299[A-Za-z ]"`  Read up to 299 string of alpha or space.
Or other `char` (like `-'.`) found in names as needed `"%299[-A-Za-z '.]"` [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy)
`" ,"`   Read any white space, comma.
`"%f"`   Read any white space, read float.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct student {
  int id;
  char name[300];
  float grade;
} Student;

int main(void) {
  Student s;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("student.txt", "a+");

  // Read line, =uses a buffer about twice expected need
  char buf[sizeof s * 2];  
  fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

  // 11, Alan Turing,3.20
  int cnt = sscanf(buf, "%d , %299[A-Za-z ] ,%f", &s.id, s.name, &s.grade);
  if (cnt != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected input, cnt = %d\n", cnt);
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
  }
  fprintf(fp, "%d,%s,%.2f\n", s.id, s.name, s.grade);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: note : The name  include a space. `[A-Za-z]`  is not allowed space.

Comment: well, The following people can not be input. `Tatum O'Neal`, `Sir Winston Leonard Spencer-Churchill`, `Harry S. Truman`..

Comment: @BLUEPIXY True - I was thinking about that driving in this morning. BTW In "Harry S. Truman", guess what "S." stand for?  (Just "S") - http://www.trumanlibrary.org/speriod.htm

Comment: He said Just "S",  but He  wrote the "S.". :-D

Comment: The space before `%299[A-Za-z ]` will discard white space after the first comma, but the space between `]` and `,` only handles white space different from SPACE, which is accepted as part of the `name`. The format should probably be `"%d , %299[^,],%f"` and `s.name` should be stripped to get rid of trailing spaces.

Comment: @chqrlie " the space between ] and , only handles white space different from SPACE, which is accepted as part of the name" --> it also consumes white-spaces like tab, after the name and white-space after a maximal long name - not only spaces.  Agree about "s.name should be stripped to get rid of trailing spaces"

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function which skips the white space.

```
//function to skip space while reading from file
void skip_space(FILE *fp)
{
    char tmp;
    do
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &tmp);
    } while (isspace(tmp) || feof(fp)); 

    fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
}
```

You can call this function wherever you want to ignore white spaces.

Comment: Note that this assumes the `FILE *` stream is seekable.  It doesn't have to be.  Terminals, pipes, and socket connections aren't seekable, for example.